# How do I asynchronously call 5 random APIs in one iteration and then repeat n iterations

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Basically, I have a problem with my code where I suspect that I'm actually running it concurrently but not in a parallel method. The problem with my results is that performing one iteration (calls 5 API ) takes on average 1 second which doesn't make sense when calling one API takes only 0.2 seconds. Hence if it was parallel, one iteration should also take roughly 0.2 secs. In short, it seems like I'm running it sequentially.

```
import concurrent.futures 
import requests 
import random
import pandas as pd
import time

#Function to determine validity of the API response 
def call_api(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        return response.status_code == 200
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False

# Load the DataFrame from your dataset
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Jose.Moquiambo\Bulk Calling 
 APIs\confidential-sales.csv")  

# Number of iterations
num_iterations = 100

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Iteration', 'Pass', 'Time Taken'])

# Variables for tracking min, max, and total time
min_time = float('inf')
max_time = float('-inf')
total_time = 0

def process_iteration(iteration):
    # Get a random sample of URLs from the DataFrame
    random_urls = df['url_column'].sample(n=5).tolist() 

    # Start timer
    start_time = time.time()

    # Execute API calls concurrently using ThreadPoolExecutor
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)as 
    executor:
      results = executor.map(call_api, random_urls)

    # Stop timer
    end_time = time.time()

    # Calculate the time taken for this iteration
    iteration_time = end_time - start_time

    # Update min, max, and total time
    global min_time, max_time, total_time
    min_time = min(min_time, iteration_time)
    max_time = max(max_time, iteration_time)
    total_time += iteration_time

  # Check if any API call was not successful in this iteration
    passed = 'Y' if all(results) else 'N'

  # Add the iteration results to the DataFrame
    results_df.loc[iteration] = [iteration, passed , iteration_time]

   # Run the iterations
for i in range(1, num_iterations + 1):
    process_iteration(i)

# Calculate average time per iteration
avg_time = total_time / num_iterations

# Display the results DataFrame
print(results_df)

# Summary statistics
print("Minimum time taken:", min_time)
print("Maximum time taken:", max_time)
print("Average time per iteration:", avg_time)
print("Y stands for error-free response and N for invalid response")
```

## Output

```
       Iteration Pass  Time Taken
 1            1    Y    1.027692
 2            2    Y    1.105409
 3            3    Y    0.998195
 4            4    Y    1.046251
 5            5    Y    1.083588
 ..         ...  ...         ...
 96          96    Y    1.119467
 97          97    Y    1.109750
 98          98    Y    1.025725
 99          99    Y    1.115403
 100        100    Y    1.114420

 [100 rows x 3 columns]
  Minimum time taken: 0.9663488864898682
  Maximum time taken: 1.529128074645996
  Average time per iteration: 1.083704767227173
  Y stands for error-free response and N for errors
```

The output is in the form of a dataframe and you can clearly see that each iteration uses up on average 1 second which is not correct when it should be roughly 0.2 secs as I checked.Therefore, it was running sequentially and not in a parallel method. Here's an example of me testing out the elapsed time.

```
response = requests.get("https://example.api.com")
print(response.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

Output:

```
0.274109
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python version 3.9.16

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: Identation fixed.

Comment: Obviously not able to test this but looks as though the API calls will be made concurrently. I suggest you add some timing debug around *requests.get()* Maybe the API response time is not as fast as you thought

Comment: No it makes sense that the API response time is fast because when i tried clicking on the url, and refreshing it, it was near instant. Definitely in the milliseconds

Comment: @JoseMoquiambo Invoking the URL from Python with *requests* is quite different to calling it from a browser. There may be header values that you could pass to improve matters - it depends on the server's requirements. Also, if you're calling the same API concurrently (albeit with different parameters) you may be constrained by the server's capabilities. Take my advice and add the timing statistics to your code

Answer (score 2):

Using a ThreadPool and its map_async functionality, you can expect good performance for your scenario.

Without access to OP's data this answer is obviously contrived but serves as a valuable pattern.

This complete program uses a flat file that contains a URL on each of its lines. The test file used has 108 different URLs that have been derived from http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/index.html

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from sys import stderr
from time import perf_counter

SAMPLES = '/Volumes/G-Drive/samples.txt'

def process(url: str) -> None:
    try:
        with requests.get(url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            print(url.split('/')[-1], response.elapsed.total_seconds())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=stderr)

def get_urls() -> list[str]:
    try:
        with open(SAMPLES) as samples:
            return list(map(str.rstrip, samples))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=stderr)
    return []

def main(urls: list[str]) -> None:
    start = perf_counter()
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        pool.map_async(process, urls).wait()
    print(f'Duration={perf_counter()-start:.2f}s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(get_urls())
```

**Output:**

```
testcat_hm.html 0.300456
testcat_io.html 0.300651
testcat_cm.html 0.308631
...
testcat_we.html 0.335705
testcat_wp.html 0.335095
testrep_red.html 0.349888
Duration=2.36s
```

**Conclusion:**

The extent of parallelism is obvious when you consider that there have been 108 GET requests each taking ~0.3s but an overall duration of <2.5s

Comment: Okay, my apologies. My code is actually indeed running in parallel. The problem was my timer was including the pool mapping thread and as well as the time to validate my response in my call_api function. Could there be a way to modify the code ?

Comment: @JoseMoquiambo Modify the code to do what? I can't rewrite it for you because a) stack**overflow** isn't really a coding service and b) I would have no way of testing any revised code

Comment: Well I realised that the timer in my code  also takes into account the  time taken for thread pool mapping as well as validating my response which is why I dont get 0.2~0.3 secs per iteration. I was wondering if there was a way to modify my code such that we calculate the time taken from the API requests such as using requests.get(url).elapsed and using it in my code should get 0.2~0.3 secs per iteration since the iteration runs in parallel

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` library itself does not provide non-blocking IO [as per documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking).

But I suggest installing and using [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures), the syntax is simple:

```py
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from pprint import pprint
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession()

futures=[session.get(f'http://httpbin.org/get?{i}') for i in range(3)]

for future in as_completed(futures):
    resp = future.result()
    pprint({
        'url': resp.request.url,
        'content': resp.json(),
    })
```

And you'll be able to gain speed from I/O blocking operations.

If you still find the execution too slow, then you may need to split your execution into multiple processes via the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package. Its use comes with higher restrictions, but does provide parallelism outside of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).

Comment: Hi, may I know how do I adjust the line 

futures=[session.get(f'http://httpbin.org/get?{i}') for i in range(3)]
to fit into my code ?

Comment: How does this improve matters over OP's multithreading approach (apart from there being less to code)?